PurgeWranglerを用いてegpuとMacを接続したい
macOS Big Sur 11.7.10のMacにPurgeWranglerを用いてegpuを接続したいです。
PCIやThunderbolt/USB4の項目を確認したところ、gpuの認識はしているようですが、ドライバが当たっていないようにみえました。
そこで、OSのアップデートをしてみましたが、自動ではドライバは当たらず。
手動でドライバを当てたいですが、Macで実施する方法はありますでしょうか。


